# passport.authenticate() is always executing failureRedirect after saving the user information in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, passport.js, session-cookies, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose

I'm a beginner to nodejs and tying to apply authentication using passport, passport-local-mongoose. I have a register page where user can enter mail id and password and click on  register button.
when user makes a post request by clicking on that button, I want to store the mailid and hash(generated using User.register method from lpassport-local-mongoose) in mongoDB.
I'm doing that using passportlocal-mongoose and then wanted to authenticate the user if there are no errors in creating the user.

```js
app.post("/register", function(req, res){

    const username = req.body.mailbox;

    User.register({username: username}, req.body.passwordbox, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
         passport.authenticate("local", successRedirect: "/secrets", failureRedirect: "/register")(req, res); 
        }
              
    })
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided context, you can try this code:

```
app.post("/register", function(req,res){ 
  const username = req.body.mailid 
  User.register({username:username}, req.body.password, function(err, user){ 
    if(!err){ 
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        res.redirect("/secrets");
      });
    } 
    else {
      res.redirect("/register");
    }
  });
});
```

following code using the **passport.authenticate()** method to authenticate the user, and providing a callback function to redirect to the secrets page if authentication is successful. If an error occurs during user creation, we redirect to the registration page.

Comment: I tried this, But instead of redirecting me to the "/secrets" page, it is showing bad request.

Comment: you need to check your express configuration then